# PHP Function Returning Incorrect Value

Tags: php

I'm having some real trouble with this, and I can't seem to figure out why. Please see code below. As you can see I have an array for `$serverDrives` set to 'C' and 'F'. I have a loop to create a new Object from a class (Drive) however when I use GetDriveLetter on the drivesArray it will always return F no matter what index I've used. I've checked that in the for loop it has both C and F, but no matter what I do I can't get it to return anything but F.

```
$serverDrives = ['C', 'F'];

$drivesArray = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($serverDrives); $i++) {
    $drivesArray[$i] = new Drive($serverDrives[$i]);
}

echo $drivesArray[0]->GetDriveLetter();
```

Here is Drive.class.php:

```
<?php
class Drive {
    public $DriveLetter;

    public function Drive($driveletter) {
        global $DriveLetter;
        $DriveLetter = $driveletter;
    }

    public function GetDriveLetter() {
        global $DriveLetter;
        return $DriveLetter;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Using `global` for a variable is rarely a good idea. Here is leads to desaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your class code to this:

```
class Drive {
    public $DriveLetter;

    public function Drive($driveletter) {
        $this->DriveLetter = $driveletter;
    }

    public function GetDriveLetter() {
        return $this->DriveLetter;
    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, but I'm curious why? What's the difference between global and using this? I assume that global is literally that, the global variable that was set last in the class? Whereas this references the Object I'm currently calling?

Comment: @user2416047 I think you can answer that yourself: if you have a global variable and return the value of that in all objects of that class, why do you expect to receive different values from different objects? You always ask the value of the single, global variable.

Comment: global means make the variable thats set elsewhere available for modification in the function. `$this` means applicable to the class

Comment: Thanks guys! I misunderstood how global works! I'll set this as the best answer when I can.